# Error CS1955: Non-invocable member 'ShoppingCartItem.GetTotal' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CKK.Logic.Models
{
   public class ShoppingCartItem
   {
      private Product product;
      private int quantity;

      public ShoppingCartItem(Product aProduct, int aQuantity)
      {
         product = aProduct;
         quantity = aQuantity;
        
      }

     public Product GetProduct()
      {
         return product;
      }

      public void SetProduct(Product value)
      {
         product = value;
      }


      public int GetQuantity()
      {
         return quantity;
      }

      public void SetQuantity(int value)
      {
         quantity = value;
      }

      public decimal GetTotal { get; }


   }
      
   }
```

Error CS1955 Non-invocable member ShoppingCartItem.GetTotal cannot be used like a method.

This is the error I'm getting and I can't seem to get around this error I would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Do you want `GetTotal` to be a property (how it's currently declared, but better renamed to just `Total`) or a method (how you're apparently trying to use it)?

Comment: I want GetTotal to be a method. I'm learning C#, and it's a school assignment. I need to create a method that will get the total when I submit my code to be tested.

Answer (score 1):

At some point in the code you haven't shown, you're trying to access the `GetTotal` property as if it were a method.

```
decimal total = item.GetTotal(); // Will not work
```

To access a property, omit the parentheses:

```
decimal total = item.GetTotal;
```

However, `GetTotal` is a poor choice of name for a property. I would suggest calling it `Total` instead.

Looking at your other methods, I'm guessing you're from a Java background? In C#, you would usually use properties instead of pairs of `Get...`/`Set...` methods:

```
public class ShoppingCartItem
{
    public ShoppingCartItem(Product product, int quantity)
    {
        Product = product;
        Quantity = quantity;
    }
    
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; }
}
```

[Properties - C# Programming Guide | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Answer (score 0):

When declaring getters and setters like this `public decimal GetTotal { get; }` in C# you are declaring a property, and not a method. So in this case you GetTotal is a property from which you can get the value like this`ShoppingCartItem.GetTotal`. As far as I can tell, GetTotal should not be a field but a method calculating the total.

I would rewrite your code like this:

```
public class ShoppingCartItem {
    private Product product {public get; public set; } //is it nessecary to have both public?
    private int quantity {public get; public set; }

    public ShoppingCartItem(Product aProduct, int aQuantity)
    {
        product = aProduct;
        quantity = aQuantity;
    }

    public decimal GetTotal {
        return product.price * quantity;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties), not a [field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields). Since C# has two distinct concepts using those names, it's best to use the right name for it.